# Reset sliding from top to bottom navbar-collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was redesigned navigation for mobile in bootstrap, when click on bar lines I writed to show from left to right pane, but now it was mixed with default sliding pane of bootstrap from top to bottom, how to delete thats default bootstrap js code.

here is code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/183/

HTML

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">ddd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <p class="navbar-text">
            <b> '.$username.' </b>
            <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-link">Logout</a>&nbsp;
          </p>  
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-collapse{
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 999999;
    width:80%;
    background-color: green;

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu ="close";

    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        if(menu == "close") {
            $('.navbar-collapse').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
            menu= "open";
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar-collapse').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-100%, 0)');
            menu="close";
        }

          });
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this almost like an Offcanvas menu on mobile, just slide in from one side instead of from the top?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-100%, 0)');
```

To this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0, -100%)');
```

Comment: no you don;t understand me, i wan't to show content from left to right , and I was implemented that with js code, but it was mxied with default bootstrap js where showing from top to bottom how to remove that default code